# How to filter Observable value in Angular 2 : Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I want to filter only bids that belong only to a project.id equal to bid.project_id in angular 2 using observables, I want to be able to filter this out before passing it to the bid component.

I have bid.ts

```
    export class Bid {
      constructor(
        public id?: number, 
        public amount?: number,
        public duration?: number,
        public description?: string,
        public project_id?: number
      ) {}
    }

    let bid: Bid = JSON.parse('{"id": id, "amount": amount, "duration": duration, "description": description, "project_id": project_id}');
```

and project.ts

```
export class Project {
  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public title?: string, // name
    public description?: string,
    public category_id?: number,
    public budget_id?: number
  ) {}
}
```

// bid.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; //Rx

import { Bid } from './bid';
import { Project } from '../projects/project';

@Injectable() 
export class BidService {
  bid: Bid
  project: Project

  private bidsUrl = 'http://localhost:3005/bids.json';

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ){}

  getBids(): Observable<Bid[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.bidsUrl)
                .map((response: Response) => <Bid[]>response.json())
                .map(bids => {
                  return bids.filter(bid => bid.project_id === this.project.id)
                })
                .catch(this.handleError)
  }
```

in bid List component I also have this

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Bid } from './bid';
import { BidService } from './bid.service';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'bid-list',
  templateUrl: 'bid-list.component.html',
  providers: [ BidService ]
})
export class BidListComponent implements OnInit {

  bids: Bid[]; 

  errorMessage: string;

  mode = "Observable";
  constructor(
    // Dependency Injection
    private bidService: BidService,

  ) {}



  ngOnInit() {
    let timer = Observable.timer(0, 5000);
    timer.subscribe(() => this.getBids());
  }

  getBids() {
    this.bidService.getBids()
        .subscribe(
          bids => this.bids = bids,
          error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
  }
}
```

How can display only the bids that belong to a project?

My problem is that Bid Object for Project with Id of 1 is displaying under project with Id of 2, the map is not working.

Comment: What's the problem? Doesn't your code do what you want?

Comment: You never initialize `project` (_or_ the `bid`) in the `BidService` class. What do you expect?

Comment: I'd use filter (http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html) instead of the map operator.

Comment: @peeskillet I expect Bids that belong to a Project to only display under that project.

Comment: I overlooked the variable `bid` from the callback. Still your `project` is not initialized. That's the reason for the error. `this.project.id` <- can't do that if `project` has not be initialized

Comment: @peeskillet project: Project is initialized in bid.service.ts. I also just tried with 
 getBids(): Observable<Bid[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.bidsUrl)
                    .filter(bid  => this.bid.project_id === this.project.id )
                    .map((response: Response) => <Bid[]>response.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError)
  } 
I got this error bid.service.ts:43 Cannot read property 'project_id' of undefined

Comment: What do you think I mean when I say "initialized"? This is not initialization: `project: Project`. That's _typing_. Initialization uses a `=`, e.g `project = new Project()`

Comment: It's weird. I do a similar one Rx only with your code and it's working. Probably you can provide more details on your sample bids json and project json? Take a look here
https://jsbin.com/hacaxitigo/edit?js,console

Comment: @Chybie I provided more details, i am getting my json obj from a rails API backend.

Comment: what if you do a test, hardcoded the value `this.project.id` to 1 or 2 and `===` to `==`? Suspecting type different

Comment: @Chybie I got this error after doing that, Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (bid.service.ts:32) using you function. getBidsService = function () {
  const service$ = Observable.of(this.bids)
              .map(x => x.filter(y => y.project_id == 25));
  return service$;
}

Comment: you should not use `const service$ = Observable.of(this.bids) .map(x => x.filter(y => y.project_id == 25)); return service$;`. The `Observable.of(this.bids)` is actually what I do to mock your `this.http`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131816/discussion-between-mayorsanmayor-and-chybie).